# How does the Framed Function Theorem simplify Cerf Theory?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, morse-theory, differential-topology

A handle decomposition of a manifold $M$ is a useful structure to carry around. It is induced by a [Morse function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_theory) $f\colon\, M\to \mathbb{R}$.
 
How are two handle decompositions of $M$ related? The space of Morse functions turns out not to be connected. But if one expands the space of Morse functions to include functions $g\colon\, M\to \mathbb{R}$ which are Morse at all but finitely degenerate times, at which birth-death singularities occur, then one obtains a connected space, via [Cerf's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cerf_theory). So any two Morse functions $F_{0,1}$ are connected by a 1-parameter family of generalized Morse functions $f_t$ with $t\in[0,1]$ devoid of the worst singularities, but which still have "mild" singularities of codimension 1. We have made progress. However, the global pattern of crossings and birth-death singularities as $t$ runs from $0$ to $1$ might still be quite involved. This pattern can be visualized as a curve in $I\times \mathbb{R}$ called a Cerf graphic (see *e.g.* [Kirby-Gay](http://www.pnas.org/content/early/2011/04/18/1018465108.full.pdf)). Our next goal is to simplify the Cerf graphic, to get rid of as many crossings and birth-death singularities as possible. This entails another expansion of our space of functions, this time allowing elliptic and hyperbolic umbilics, and swallowtails, which are worse sorts of singularities.
An alternative idea to embed the space of Morse functions in a connected space of functions, which does not involve swallowtails and umbilics, is to introduce framed functions. A framed function is a generalized Morse function (Morse at all but finitely many degenerate times, at which birth-death singularities occur), together with an orthonormal framing of the negative eigenspace at the Hessian of the function $f$ at each critical point of $f$. Amazingly, it turns out that the space of framed functions is connected and contractible (see *e.g.* [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38347/the-space-of-framed-functions)). This is (one version of) the Framed Function Theorem.
It's silly, but I'm having difficulty understanding how everything now fits together. I'm interested in the context of TQFT's, in which I would like to slice a manifold with boundary into simple pieces using a height function (in particular, I'm working with compact manifolds rather than with closed manifolds). In order to do this, my Morse functions need to be especially nice, in that they should not have level surfaces crossing the boundary, because then slicing would create corners.

> How does the Framed Function Theorem simplify Cerf Theory? Does it completely replace it (in the sense that I can use the Framed Function Theorem instead of Cerf's Theorem to prove the Kirby Theorem (or pretty-much anything else Cerf's Theorem is used for), for example), because I no longer need swallowtails and elliptic and hyperbolic umbilics?

I'm asking this question primarily in order to motivate myself to look more seriously at understanding framed functions. I'd like to understand how exactly they fit into the bigger story first.

Comment: Another approach to simplification of Cerf theory is via Hatcher's space $Wh$ and his parametric $h$-cobordism theorem (see section 1.4 in http://folk.uio.no/rognes/papers/plmf.pdf concerning the history of corrections of its statement and proof). In the case of links in $S^3$, this should amount to reducing/relating the Kirby calculus to some sort of transformations on $3$-manifold spines. Understanding the details of this would be really cool.

Comment: The link in Sergey Melikhov's comment is broken, but it seems to be available currently at https://www.mn.uio.no/math/personer/vit/rognes/papers/plmf.pdf and be the paper titled "Spaces of PL Manifolds and Categories of Simple Maps" by Waldhausen, Jahren, and Rognes.

Comment: Shortly after this question was posted, Elaisberg and Mishachev published a very relevant paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.1000 "The Space of Framed Functions is Contractible"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The framed function theorem tells you that up to "contractible choice" a compact manifold admits a framed function: i.e., a function as you prescribe. Furthermore, a framed function is supposed to give you a cell structure on the manifold up to contractible choice.

**Note:** The framing data is there to give you an explicit coordinatization of the cells.

(Actually, Igusa only showed that the space of framed functions is $n$-connected, where $n$ is the dimension of the domain manifold, but ideas of Eliashberg are supposed to give contractibility).

This is supposed to give rise to an alternate proof of Waldhausen's celebrated theorem $$A(X) \simeq Q(X_+)\times \text{Wh}^{\text{diff}}(X).$$

One idea in the proof is roughly this: suppose for simplicity that $X =\ast$ is a point.
Then there is a model (the "expansion space") for  $\text{Wh}^{\text{diff}}(\ast)$ that is a moduli space of finite, contractible, based cell complexes. That is, a point in the expansion space is a point contractible finite cell complex and the topology is defined so that a perturbations are of three kinds: (1) sliding cells over each other, (2) a refinement of the partial ordering of the cells, and (3) an elementary expansion/contraction.

Now suppose that $p : E \to B$ is a smooth fiber bundle whose fibers are contractible manifolds $E_t$ (for $t\in B$; for example, a bundle of $h$-cobordisms of a disk is such a case). Then the framed function theorem implies that $E$ can be equipped with a fiberwise framed function
$f: E \to \Bbb R$.

Now here is the difficult step: the framed function on each $f_t: E_t\to \Bbb R$ is supposed to give rise to a based cell structure on $E_t$ which varies continuously in $t$; these are 
supposed to amount to a parametrized family of cell complexes, i.e., a map $B \to \text{Wh}^{\text{diff}}(*)$.

Unfortunately, none of these ideas have appeared (there is a preprint by Igusa and Waldhausen which is supposed to do just this, but it never was released).  In my Ph.D. thesis (written in 1989 under the direction of Igusa), I manage to give the details of the geometric construction of the family of cell complexes in the special case of a fiberwise framed Morse function, that is, I assumed there were no birth/death singularities in the family. The associated family of cell complexes had cell slides but no elementary expansions/collapses.

Comment: Wow! So if I read correctly, your answer is "yes"? When all these ideas appear, the Framed Function Theory will effectively replace Cerf Theory? At least, the "difficult step" will recover Kirby's theorem?

Comment: In effect yes. It supercedes Cerf Theory. Cerf theory is the one-parameter special case. Also, in some sense Waldhausen theory is a stabilized version of Cerf theory (where the manifolds are stabilized with respect to dimension by taking the product with disks).

Comment: John, is the difficulty in the difficult step related to the difference between Wh$^{\rm Diff}$ and Wh$^{\rm PL}$? I suspect that for purposes such as justification of Kirby's calculus doing everything piecewise-linearly would simplify matters by omitting a huge chunk of Cerf theory that amounts to proving that a PL 4-manifold has a unique Diff structure. So, would not the PL version of the generalized Cerf theory, in the form of the parametrized PL $h$-cobordism theorem, give a shorter route to such applications?

Comment: Sergey, I don't think that's the issue. What I was alluding to was a different program for showing Waldhausen's theorem on $A(X)$ which relates $A(X)$ to geometry (in the simplest case: the space of stabilized $h$-cobordisms of a disk is supposed to map to $\text{Wh}^{\text{diff}}(\ast)$ as a homotopy equivalence.

The real difficulty is to write down the appropriate map. The expansion space approach gives an alternate description of 
 $\text{Wh}^{\text{diff}}(\ast)$ as a moduli space of cell complexes. 

The difficulty a lot to do with the geometry of the birth/death singularities.

Comment: Sergey, what was actually published by Jahren-Rognes-Waldhausen was also very difficult: The idea of that proof is to relate: (0) $A(\ast)$ (which is defined using based simplicial sets) to classifying spaces of (1) finite polyhedra and then to (2) categories of manifolds. The passage from (0) to (1) takes up the bulk of their paper, and the passage from (1) to (2) goes via thickening theory (which is in essence the reverse direction to Morse theory.

Comment: (Oops, a bit too many *diff*s in one line.)

Comment: John, thanks for details. I have no idea about the passage from (0) to (1), but is it needed for Kirby's theorem? Then, I don't see any difficulty with writing down the map from the space of stabilized PL $h$-cobordisms of a manifold $M$ to Wh$^{\rm PL}(M)$ (though showing it's a homotopy equivalence certainly needs work). Perhaps we're speaking about different spaces. By Wh$^{\rm PL}$ I mean the classifying space of the category whose objects are finite posets and whose morphisms are order-preserving maps with contractible point-inverses. (Wh$^{\rm PL}(M)$ is then clear.) 

Comment: Now there is a special type of a morphism $f:X\to Y$ which I call a subdivision and Mnev calls an assembly; the definition is that the geometric realization of $f^{−1}(Y_{\le p})$ is PL homeomorphic to the cone over the geometric realization of $f^{−1}(Y_{<p})$ keeping the latter fixed, for each $p\in Y$. We then have a smaller category, whose objects are finite posets with geometric realization a PL manifold, and morphisms just the subdivisions (to be cont'd)

Comment: Let me anyway say that $Wh^{\rm PL}(M)$, where $M$ is a specific poset with geometric realization a PL manifold, is the classifying space of the category whose objects are that of the original category containing $M$ as a subposet, and morphisms are that of the original category fixed on $M$. Now $BH^{\rm PL}(M)$ will be the classifying space of the category whose objects are those of the smaller category that contain $M$ as a subposet and are PL homeomorphic to $M\times [0,1]$ extending the identification $M=M\times\{0\}$, and morphisms are those of the smaller category fixed on $M$. 

Comment: There is something non-trivial that you might be glossing over in the PL case: you need to choose an explicit triangulation to get from an h-cobordism to a simplicial complex (or finite poset). In any case, as I've said Jahren-Rognes-Waldhausen go the other way.  

Concerning Kirby's theorem, I simply have know idea since I've never thought about that. My "answer" to Daniel's question had to do with the framed function theorem as a replacement for Cerf theory. The original application of Cerf theory was to pseudoisotopies. 

Comment: Note: The triangulation is not a priori part of the structure. Also Note: for an $h$-cobordism $W$ from $M$ to $N$, we are looking for a way to produce *relative* triangulation of $W$ (that is relative to $M$). There is no canonical way to accomplish that.

Comment: ("Original category"=from the first comment, "smaller category"=from the second comment; sorry for being slow, I have to recall these things.) In the above, $M$ has no boundary; if it does, the homeomorphism must send $\partial M\times I$ to itself. Finally, the map $dirlim_n BH^{\rm PL}(M\times I^n)\to Wh^{\rm PL}(M)$ is the identity on objects, and may adjust a morphism by composing it with a  projection. Does it help?

Comment: Thanks, John, I'll think about the relative triangulation issue. As for the absolute one, indeed I was avoiding it, but it seems to have been treated by Mnev, http://arxiv.org/abs/0708.4039

Comment: Also, the issue of non-canonical triangulations is not going to be very hard in the one-parameter case - in that case Hatcher's original (rather short) arguments should apply already. 

Comment: John, I'm not convinced that "triangulation is not a priori part of the structure". A PL manifold (or polyhedron) is a space with a compatible family of triangulations. Such objects don't even form a set, so Jahren-Rognes-Waldhausen always fix an embedding in $\Bbb R^\infty$. Is it any better than fixing a triangulation? Even so, this is a highly non-constructive definition of a polyhedron, and the only way I know to make it combinatorial is via Alexander's theorem on stellar subdivisions. But we don't have such a parametrized theorem. The trouble with non-constructiveness is that whenever ...

Comment: Concerning your definition of $\text{Wh}^{\text{PL}(M)$---that's not the definition Waldhausen gives. The usual definition the cofiber of the assembly map $(M_+) \wedge A(\ast) \to A(M)$ (Waldhausen gives a specific model for the domain of the assembly map which is the $K$-theory of the category of simple maps (When $M = \ast$, a simple map is a map of based finite simplicial sets which as contractible point inverses). My recollection is that its highly non-trivial to show that the cofiber of the assembly map is equivalent to the definition you are giving. 

Comment: ... we're concerned with any real geometric application, we won't be able to use a theorem that we cannot even state in an effective language. So the only formulation of the parametrized PL h-cobordism theorem that I understand is the one that I gave above. And it does work: if we have an $n$-parameter pseudo-isotopy, $n$ finite, it is easy to triangulate it by an $n$-parameter pseudo-isotopy of posets in the above sense, extending the given triangulation of $M$ (this is similar to Hatcher's "iterated mapping cylinder decomposition").

Comment: My definition of Wh$^{\rm PL}(M)$ is implicit in Steinberger's paper that Jahren-Rognes-Waldhausen cite. Mnev mentions it explicitly. I suspect that my version of the parametrized PL $h$-cobordism theorem above would be easiest to prove in the same language of posets.

Comment: Okay, that's fine. I understand what you are trying to say. The Jahren-Rognes-Waldhausen paper contains a version of Hatcher' parametrized h-cobordism theorem + other stuff, the latter which relates your definition of the Whitehead space to the categorical definition (as you know doubt know, Hatcher's original statement was never proved; the J-R-W paper proves a modified version). The "other stuff" is where the  triangulations and/or thickenings are to be implemented.

By the way, in your definition of the PL Whitehead space, can you please be more explicit as to the morphisms you are using?

Comment: ....and the "other stuff" I mentioned above is needed to relate manifolds to higher algebraic K-theory. As far as geometry goes, you're correct. By the way, what I called "categorical definition" is taken by me to mean using Waldhausen's machinery.

Comment: Objects are finite posets, morphisms are order-preserving maps whose point-inverses have contractible geometric reazilations (let me call these CE-maps). Is there anything wrong with that? For Wh$^{PL}(P)$, where P is a poset, objects are finite posets $Q$ containing $P$ as a subposet and such that the inclusion $|P|\to |Q|$ is a homotopy equivalence (sorry this I forgot to say!) and morphisms are CE-maps fixed on $P$.

Comment: Sergey, I just looked at Mnev's paper (which I wasn't aware of before). That's really cool! A naive thought occurs to me: I wonder if it can be used to give a combinatorial description of Pontryagin classes.

Comment: Sergey, I realize now why it took me so long to understand what you are writing. Your definition of the Whitehead space is not the same as Waldhausen's and to equate the two, one needs to prove a theorem.

Comment: John, I've heard several talks on this subject (combinatorial formulas for characteristic classes from Mnev's work) by Georgy Sharygin in 2010 (you can find his email on the arxiv). Somewhat related work is being done by Alexander Gaifullin (see his papers on the arxiv). I appreciate your answers and I realize that the parametrized PL $h$-cobordism theorem as stated above, and certainly the high connectivity of the PL stabilization map, may not have optimal proofs in the literature, so maybe they do not yet fully qualify as discrete generalized Cerf theory. I hope to work on this some day.

Comment: I also think that the Hatcher-Steinberger result that Wh$^{\rm PL}$ classifies PL fibrations, and especially Mnev's result that BH$^{\rm PL}$ as defined above classifies PL bundles are proved way harder than they could be. The problem (which Mnev emphasizes in his section 1.2) arises because they want to triangulate the base by a simplicial complex, and I think it will disappear completely if we triangulate the base by a poset. Apparently this does not simplify all of Mnev's theory, only one its consequence.

Comment: I have a message written to me from John Rognes which compares what Mnev did to what J-R-W do. If you wish to I can send it to you.

Comment: That'd be great! melikhov (at) mi.ras.ru

Comment: John, for Pontryagin - this is going and using higher torsions stuff of cause.